# How to use volume as a feature in ML models for predicting stock prices?

Tags: trading

What is a good way to use trading volume as a feature in machine learning models for predicting stock prices? Z-score? Which period: day, week, month?

Comment: Stock prices are not predictable.  If they were, machine learning programs would make Warren Buffet look like an amateur.

Comment: Try them all and backtest to see which one did the best job of actually predicting prices.

Comment: I need more ideas, what to try

Comment: You would probably get better responses at https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have several ideas here already; why not try those?

Comment: Done, not very successful

Comment: Trading volume and stock price are likely to often be related in the opposite direction of what you want-- prices driving trade volume, rather than trade volume providing information on future prices. Do you have a specific reason to think that the volume provides some information on the future price? The answer to that question may also answer this one.